# Mercurial hgwebdir configuration URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mercurial

I'm setting up an hgwebdir configuration for the first time with Mercurial on apache2. I can see the three repositories I've set up in the first page, and I've figured out how to modify their names so they don't resemble the directory path.

But when I click to go to one of the repositories, the URL becomes http://localhost/hg/hgweb.cgi/path/to/repos. I would like the directory to be http://localhost/hg/name instead as that is easier to remember for people who want to clone the repository.

Is there anyway to do that with hgwebdir?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the web server you are using.

In my case I'm using Apache and simply edited the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and for the domain running `hgweb.cgi` set up the following Script Alias:

```
ScriptAlias /hg /FULL/PATH/TO/hgweb.cgi
```

Also I see you are referring to `hgwebdir.cgi` script. This has since been merged with the `hgweb.cgi` script since version 1.6. You can get the latest version of this file from the Mercurial source repository:

> http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg/raw-file/stable/hgweb.cgi